# Very Slow MySQL Performance on NAS

Tags: mysql, mariadb, nas

Just got myself a Asustor NAS to handle my videos, pictures, music and etc.
Having both a Desktop and a Notebook in the house, I figured it would be a good idea to setup my database on the NAS (which already comes with MariaDB preinstalled).

The Setup: RAID 1, max read speads of about 110MB/s from the disk, connected via 1.3 Mbps WiFi with gigabit connection. Getting about 60MB/s using BlackMagic Benchmark.

The query:

```
    SELECT items.title, items.discount, items.qtd, items.price,  ((price * qtd) - discount) AS total, DATE_FORMAT(orders.created_at, '%m-%y')
    FROM items
    INNER JOIN orders ON orders.order_id = items.order_id
    ORDER BY created_at;
```

The table `orders` has about 1.8k rows, the table `items` has about 4.7k rows. The query affects 5k rows and takes between 4.8 to 7.0 seconds to run, which seems absurd for such a simple query. I used to run the same query in my localhost (ok, it is a NVMe SSD, which I get is a lot faster), on milliseconds. `order_id` is a VARCHAR with about 10 characters in it.

It took about 7 (9 last time) minutes to insert all the data in all tables:

```
`orders` - 1.7k rows, 11 columns
`items` - 4.8k rows, 12 columns
`customers` - 1.7k rows, 9 columns
```

My question:

1. Is it really that bad of a performance, or am I getting the wrong performance benchmark after having used NVMe SSD's?
2. If it is bad indeed, what can I do to improve it (still hosting my DB on my NAS)?
3. What could I expect performance-wise on an online hosted database?

Thanks a lot.

```
**Tables:**
`CREATE TABLE `orders` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `order_id` varchar(15) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'VA',
  `created_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `gateway` varchar(25) DEFAULT NULL,
  `total` decimal(15,0) DEFAULT NULL,
  `subtotal` decimal(15,0) DEFAULT NULL,
  `status` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `discounts` decimal(15,0) DEFAULT NULL,
  `total_price` decimal(15,0) DEFAULT NULL,
  `order_number` varchar(15) DEFAULT NULL,
  `processing` varchar(15) DEFAULT NULL,
  `customer_id` varchar(15) DEFAULT NULL,
  `number` varchar(15) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `number` (`number`),
  UNIQUE KEY `order_id` (`order_id`),
  KEY `customer_id` (`customer_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1712 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;`
```

Comment: Please show `SHOW CREATE TABLE {tablename}` for the tables, and `EXPLAIN {query}`. Its also possible that your MariaDB isn't optimally configured. How much ram does the NAS have spare? What version of MariaDB is installed (`SELECT VERSION()`? What does `SHOW GLOBAL STATUS` show on MariaDB? If you are importing/updating often increasing the `innodb_log_file_size` may be needed.

Comment: 1.3 Mbps WiFi with gigabit connection? Is gigabit the wired connection?

Comment: The connection is: input internet from ISP modem to router (Archer C7), and plug NAS to router RJ45 port. The router has a gigabit connection (router x NAS), and it has 1.3Mbps on 5Ghz band... I connect on my desktop via WiFi, but given that the router/cable shouldn't be a bottleneck, I was expecting more of it.... the NAS is the Asustor AS1002T, it has 512 RAM I guess, and while working with the DB the CPU is at about 5% and memory 45%...

Comment: Can't post create table as it's too long, but it's basically 12 columns each, `1 PK`, `2UK`, `2FK`, 8 `VARCHAR (255)`, 4 `DECIMALS (25)` - they are all similar in format. Explain Query: `"Simple"` Select type, `All` Type for on line, `ref` for the other, `key_len = 48`, `1710 rows`, `Extra: Using Where; Using filesort`. 10.0.28 MariaDB... Don't know what to look for on `SHOW GLOBAL STATUS`

Comment: `SHOW GLOBAL STATUS LIKE  'innodb%'`; looking for buffer pool pages used/not used etc. See if you can put the explain info/show create tables without `SHOW GLOBAL STATUS`. `All` / `Using where/ filesort` indicates your indexes aren't right (ref [query optmization](https://github.com/jynus/query-optimization)).

Comment: `Buffer Pool` mostly OFF, `Pool_Size` is `134217728`... probably not optimized indeed, I'll check into that, but still 20 inserts/second seems a bit odd...

Comment: edit the question and put the info there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Is it really that bad of a performance, or am I getting the wrong performance benchmark after having used NVMe SSD's?

Yes this is kind of bad performance. Correct indexing for the query will go part way in solving the performance problem of the query. Getting to get the NAS to use innodb_buffer_pool and free memory as disk cache is going to be difficult with only 512M on board.

2. If it is bad indeed, what can I do to improve it (still hosting my DB on my NAS)?

Correct indexing of tables with help the join and order. Design changes to use integer primary keys for joins. As a first step, if `order_id` really isn't utf8 and is just latin1 changing for that column that would make the key smaller, could change this to the primary key too.

As this is an entire two tables data search in the query, its only going to eliminate IO latency if it can all stay in RAM.

3. What could I expect performance-wise on an online hosted database?

Hosted database will offer more RAM, and probably a faster CPU.

Comment: thanks lot, I'll check my buffer pool and see what can I do to optimize the structure. I still find it quite odd that even when I change from say VARCHAR 255 to VARCHAR 50, it takes a few moments for Sequel Pro to process it... I'll keep digging. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

My NAS mysql version is **Mariadb 10.3.29** , blow change work for me , you can try it!

- `/volume1/@appstore/MariaDB10/usr/local/mariadb10/etc/mysql/my.cnf`
- Change

  ```
  #innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit = 1
  ```

  TO

  ```
  innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit = 0
  ```
- Restart MySQL

----OR----

- Login MySQL
- `SET GLOBAL innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit=0;`
- You can change it on runtime and check the different!